# Can't get my computer to recognize my vintage keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, input-devices, additional-drivers

Vintage Mouse/Keyboard new OS and computer

Okay so I have this Liteon SK-6000 model keyboard and a Logitech model M-C48 mouse that I’ve been trying to figure out how to get working on my desktop just because I think they’re pretty cool pieces of tech. I’ve got PS/2 to USB adapters on the keyboard and the mouse is plugged into the keyboard so the SK-6000 is the only thing interfacing with the actual computer. The lights on the keyboard flash when I boot but then it’s like the computer doesn’t even recognize the keyboard is plugged in (based on lsusb output, it isn’t there). I’ve installed drivers for it but is there some way to enable PS/2 support or something through the command line? I only just started using Linux last week so take it easy on me if I’m just being an idiot.

Comment: "enable PS/2 support" but you do not use ps/2... you use usb with a ps/2 connector. It is more likely the connector is the problem. `lsusb` -has- to show at least the usb adapter plugged in.  ps/2 might not be able to tell the system what it is but that is not really needed for it to work.  "The lights on the keyboard flash when I boot " The way they flash might be a code ;-)  "I’ve installed drivers" ehm how? what drivers? seems odd... ps/2 and usb do not reqiore extra drivers.

Comment: ah might have found the issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/48792/how-to-enable-an-extern-keyboard-using-ps2-to-usb-adapter-on-a-notebook   Wrong ps/2 - usb adapter: you need on with a circuit.

Comment: You haven't provided any OS/release details which are the starting point I'd suggest you provide. Either way I'm currently using *kinetic* and IBM Aug-1990 model M keyboard with no changes to the OS at all. My box doesn't have a PS2 connector; so I just have it plugged into a USB-PS2 convertor & all releases of Ubuntu have used it (*or my other old favorite Model M keyboards*).  I've never had any issue with working PS2 keyboards/mice.

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating any hub between the keyboard and the host.  I have a laptop which works with an old PS2 keyboard when plugged directly into a USB3 port, but just lights up with no keys active when plugged into an attached hub on another USB3 port.

However, it's probably the keyboard, another identical KB works fine in either place. with either of two PS2/USB adapters.